# Python for loop nested in if else loop

Tags: python

Can anyone help to solve my following question, sorry I might not express clearly in the title.

```
myList = ['val', 'val2', 'val3']

def myfunction():
    if condition1:
        topic = "string1"
    elif condition2:
        topic = "string2"
    elif condition3:
        for val in myList:
            topic = string3.replace('str', val)
    else:
        topic = "string4"
    return topic
```

When `condition3` is met, `myfunction` will only return the last value of `myList`.
In this case, how to make the code return all combinations of "string3" + value in `myList`?

Please advise. Thanks

==Edit==

Edited code in question

I would like the function to return

```
valing3
val2ing3
val3ing3
```

Comment: replace `topic = "string3" + val` with `topic += val`

Comment: How do you want it returned? Do you want a list of elements like `["string3"+val1, "string3"+val2, …]`? Or a string like `"string3"+val1+"string3"+val2+ …`? Can you please add an example of what you want your function to return?

Answer (score 1):

```
myList = ['val', 'val2', 'val3']

def myfunction():
    if condition1:
        topic = "string1"
    elif condition2:
        topic = "string2"
    elif condition3:
        topic = "string3"
        for val in myList:
            topic = topic + val 
    else:
        topic = "string4"
    return topic
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
myList = ['val', 'val2', 'val3']

def myfunction():
    if condition1:
        topic = "string1"
    elif condition2:
        topic = "string2"
    elif condition3:
        topic = ["string3" + val for val in myList]
    else:
        topic = "string4"
    return topic
```